# Create a histogramm and add the rank above the histogram

Tags: r

My question may be stupid but I could not solve by my own. I have a data which show the sports activiy by year from 1995 to 2015 like this

| Year | Sportsactivity (h) |
| --- | --- |
| 1995 | 300 |
| 1996 | 299 |
| 1997 | 315 |
| 1998 | 286 |
| 1999 | 275 |
| 2000 | 302 |
| 2001 | 304 |
| 2002 | 301 |
| 2003 | 320 |
| 2004 | 342 |
| 2005 | 333 |
| 2006 | 355 |
| 2007 | 370 |
| 2008 | 366 |
| 2009 | 364 |
| 2010 | 362 |
| 2011 | 358 |
| 2012 | 356 |
| 2013 | 354 |
| 2014 | 323 |
| 2015 | 298 |

Now I would like to create a histogram

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, y=Sportsactivity)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+
ggtitle("Sportsactivity with rank the year")
```

How can I add the rank above every year in the bar chart corresponding to the year?

For example 2007 should have the number one above its bar line

Comment: No problem, your code works well

Comment: I was first confusing with the half numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With simulated data, here is an example where you use `rank` function to rank observations values and `geom_text` to add the text with `vjust` to adjust on vertical axis.

```
### Import library
library(ggplot2)

### Data-management
data <- data.frame(Year=1995:2015, Sportsactivity=round(rnorm(21, 310, 15)))
data$rank <- rank(data$Sportsactivity)

### ggplot with geom_text
ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, y=Sportsactivity)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  ggtitle("Sportsactivity with rank the year") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(rank,1)), vjust=-.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you have half numbers?

Comment: It happens when you have twice the same value, you can of course round or tail your values. Won't happen with your dataset

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by dplyr functionalities.

- arrange + mutate and row_number() for modification of your data frame
- geom_label for labeling

You can do both within ggplot or modify your data frame first

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Year, y=Sportsactivity)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label = nrow(data)-rank(Sportsactivity)+1), size = 10, vjust = 2, colour = "white") +
  ggtitle("Sportsactivity with rank the year")
```

[image]